# How do I dynamically update my grouped bar chart using d3js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, visualization

I have successfully managed to create a grouped bar chart that displays the various performance stats for soccer players over the course of one season. This data is all loaded from a csv file. I would now like to dynamically change that data whereby when a button is pressed, a new csv file is loaded with the stats corresponding to the next soccer season. I've tried to do this on my own but everytime I try reload the data, the old data as well as the old axis's remain present and the enw data loads ontop of these. It all ends up looking messy. So how do I have the old bars and axises updated in line with the new data? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("SoccerStatsCSV.csv", function(error, data) {
  console.log(data);
  var playerNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Attribute"; });
  console.log(playerNames);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Playerstats = playerNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
    console.log(d.Playerstats);
  });    

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Attribute; }));
  x1.domain(playerNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.Playerstats, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Units");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Attribute) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.Playerstats; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(playerNames.slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; }); 





});





//The updating button

d3.select("button")
  .on('click',function(){ 
d3.csv("SoccerStatsCSV2008.csv", function(error, data) {
  console.log(data);
  var playerNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Attribute";    });
  console.log(playerNames);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Playerstats = playerNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
   console.log(d.Playerstats);
  });    

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Attribute; }));
  x1.domain(playerNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.Playerstats, function(d) {     return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Units");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Attribute) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.Playerstats; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(playerNames.slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



});
});




});
```

Comment: You will have to add an enter-update-exit segment: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/

Comment: you should select your svg and remove them. I suggest you add an id to your svg, and then when pushing the button you may do a "d3.selectAll("#svg_id").remove()" (note that the # is here to search a specific id within the DOM)

Comment: SO essentially once I have removed the svg as well as all of its components, I will have to rebuild everything within the "on click" function?

Comment: All i want are for the individual bars to animate up or down based on the new data that i dynamically load when the button is pushed